# Compute checksum similarity

Tags: c#, .net

I posted yesturday about computing the similarity in percentage the difference between 2 files using the amount of words that appear in 1 but not the other.. this was a bad way of doing the job so i thought a better way would be to make a MD5 or CRC checksum of both files and compute the difference using that .. making the checksum is the easy part but I'm unsure of how to go about determining the difference, I know getting the percentage goes something along these lines:

```
    double sameWordPercentage = (1.0 * n / m) * 100;
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(sameWordPercentage, 2)  + "% Similar");
```

thanks for any help.. just dont have a clear image of how i'm going to do this, maybe some pseudo code would help also.

Comment: ..is your question how to get a percentage difference from a hash? You're aware that will be highly inaccurate.. ?

Comment: Cryptographic hashes like MD5 are designed to produce a very different result for a very small change. They're completely unsuitable for determining the similarity of two files. The same applies, although to a slightly lesser extend, to checksums like CRC.

Comment: What are you trying to acomplish with this similarity index ? Document similarity is a very active research topic and many simlilarity algorithms exists some of them are very simple, some others very complex. The best approach depends of what are you going to do with this index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both MD5 and CRC are hashing algorithms that output very different results for similar inputs (and that's by design).

I think you'd better check some [Locality-sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing) algorithm like [MinHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash), as they recommend in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247640/hash-function-to-index-similar-text).

Answer (score 1):

Any hash in normal meaning will loose way to much information to make similarity comparison meaningful. Crypto hashes (MD5, SHA1/SHA256,...) are pretty much guaranteed to be useless for such comparison as they explicitly produce very different values from similar inputs.

You need to construct some special "hash". I.e. use list of indexes of known word (like "house", "door", "window") as hash. Than see if 2 files you are planning to compare have similar list of words (would be very cheap check if both lists of word indexes are sorted).